# SQL case when with 2 different types of output

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Table

```
c1     c2  c3
'a1'   1   'hi'
'b1'   2   'hee'
'c1'   3   null
```

When I do

```
select case when c3 is null then c2 else c1 end from Table
```

I get a "Conversion failed when converting" error.

I know that case when can only return 1 type, but is there a way to convert varchar to int/tinyint? If not, is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select case when c3 is null then CAST(c2 AS VARCHAR(10)) else c1 end from Table
```

you are mixing numeric and string data types.  you will be required to use as string `VARCHAR`, `CHAR`, etc.

By casting your numeric data `CAST(c2 AS VARCHAR(10))` you can solve the issue.

I guess for fun and to be more accurate in sql-server you could keep it as an `integer` but it would require to `cast as sql_variant` which would then make the entire field `sql_variant` and require casting for any use thereafter and you would gain **0 benefit** because you could always test for `IIF(ISNUMERIC(CASE)=1,CAST(value as INT),NULL)`....  Probably too much for this answer.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (C1 CHAR(2), c2 INT, c3 VARCHAR(4))

INSERT INTO @Table (C1, c2, c3)
VALUES ('a1', 1, 'hi'), ('b1',2,'hee'),('c1',3,null)

SELECT *
    ,CASE WHEN c3 is null THEN CAST(c2 AS sql_variant) else c1 end
FROM
    @Table
```

Comment: I feel silly for not thinking of converting int>varchar rather than varchar>int. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: @eric No worries, glad it helped out! Even after years of writing code I forget the cast sometimes and have to chase down the issue it happens to all of us. (can I say all? I think so...) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

From your example data it looks like you'd be better off converting to varchar rather than to int since depending on the value in c3 the output will either be a string or an integer. An integer can always be converted to a varchar, but a varchar can only be converted to an integer if it's a number. By inspection the items in c1 are not numbers. You can use a convert or a cast function.

Comment: I feel silly for not thinking of converting int>varchar rather than varchar>int. Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

I guess other than converting to int to varchar, there's no other way. But int>varchar works.